# Understanding the Importance and Definitions of Classical, Blitz, and Rapid Chess World Championships

Tags: grandmaster, world-championship, blitz, rapid

I'm intrigued by the various formats of chess world championships, specifically the classical, blitz, and rapid tournaments. My understanding is that each of these championships holds a distinct place in the chess world, but I'm looking to deepen my understanding of their significance and how they are perceived among top-level players.

How is the Classical Chess World Championship format viewed in comparison to Blitz and Rapid championships? What significance does it hold for professional players, and how does it impact their standing or legacy in the chess community?

How significant are each of these tournaments for grandmasters, and which is more commonly associated with top-level grandmasters?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, it really boils down to how your brain works, how great is your memory, do you prefer to trade off pieces and battle it out in the endgame, are you very strong with openings, are middle game tactics where you shine.

Grandmasters aside, each type (Classical, Rapid, Blitz, I don't consider bullet chess) plays into a different way of thinking and a different way of playing depending on your, or a particular player's style, each would either play to or against a player's abilities.

Personally I prefer Rapid, my brain is too slow for blitz and I can't, focus to the degree that Classical requires, so Rapid is my preferred format. I'm about 1500 in Rapid and I've beaten 1700+ blitz players, in rapid, but I do not Stand a chance against a 1000 ranked blitz player.

To answer your question, it just depends; generally people in all walks of life will say that what they are doing is the best, so if you ask an old Russian master they'll tell you that Blitz rots your brain and is stupid, if you ask a blitz champion they'll tell you the opposite.

However I do believe that it is generally accepted that classical chess is the gold standard of chess.